# How to use bedtools coverage to assess genome assembly?

Tags: dna-sequence, genome

I have been attempting to use "bedtools coverage" command to try and assess the coverage of my genomic assembly and the existance of any inversions etc. I must have a fundamental misunderstanding about something: I used BWA to create a BAM file from my illumina reads and a reference genome. I was under the impression that this BAM file was the comparison of my reads to said genome. Why then do I need to input a genome to bedtools coverage -- shouldn't my BAM file already contain the relevant genome? Any suggestions on how to deal with this or what the appropriate second input would be?

Answer (score 1):

bedtools coverage doesn't need you genome. you only need your bam file and the genome size file.

I guess their name indeed bit of confusing. Although if you see their example for "-d"

https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/genomecov.html

"my.genome" just have two column that first column is chromosome while 2nd column is the size of column.

They need this if your input is bed file I guess they just didn't bother to specifically support bam file by reading the header.